# Printing a document getting via ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where I want to print a document, which I an getting through a ajax call in a button click.

The print Pop Up is appearing in button click, but with a empty document.[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkoWf.png)

I checked the call, it's returning the valid document but not getting reflected in the pop up.

Code what I am using is:

```
var url = window.apiUrl;
    url = url + "/GetDocument";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: url,            
    }).done(function (data) {
        try {

            var winparams = 'dependent=yes,locationbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,' +
      'resizable,screenX=50,screenY=50,width=850,height=1050';

            var htmlPop = '<embed width=100% height=100%'
                             + ' type="application/pdf"'
                             + ' src="data:application/pdf;base64,'
                             + escape(data)
                             + '"></embed>';

            var printWindow = window.open("", "PDF", winparams);
            printWindow.document.write(htmlPop);
            printWindow.print();
            printWindow.close();
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

    }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        console.log(xhr);
    });
```

Can some one please tell me what am i missing.

Comment: you are getting pdf and want to write in document ?

Comment: I am getting a Document and want to print it as a PDF

Answer (score 0):

A more safer approach to get what you want is to use a third party library known as [print.js](http://printjs.crabbly.com/)
I have used it across different browser and it works fine.

A simple example would be:

```
$http({
url: "",
method: "GET",
headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/pdf"
},
responseType: "arraybuffer"
 }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
var pdfFile = new Blob([data], {
    type: "application/pdf"
});
var pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfFile);
printJS(pdfUrl);
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
console.log("something went wrong")
});
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to use any third party library. Is it possible to do as I am trying to.